# Splitting awked string in data format

Tags: awk

I need to parse awked string:

```
dd.mm.yyyy %H:%M:%S into yyyy-mm-dd %H:%M:%S
```

example:

```
10.04.2017 10:15:05 into 2017-04.10 10:15:05
```

I need awk because file is big, and only one column is data with "|" delimiter. Column number $3.

Tried splitting, but I'm stuck on:

```
awk -F"|" '{split($3,data," "}' | awk '(split(data[3],data2,"."}
```

cannot get data from data to print variables in necessary order.

Comment: `dd.mm.yyyy %H:%M:%S into yyyy-mm-dd %H:%M:%S` this is the whole input string, or rather the input is only the `dd.mm.yyyy %H:%M:%S` part? Can you reformat the post? Can you separate input from output and post it in separate code blocks? `only one column is data with "|" delimiter` - there is no `|` character in the example input you presented.

Comment: Something like `awk -F'|' '{n=split($3, a, " "); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { print a[i] }}'`?

Comment: not clear request. please provide some lines of input, and expected output.

Comment: What does `only one column is data with "|" delimiter` mean? Don't just show the string you want transformed, show it in context among other (3 or 4) fields within a few (3 or 4) lines of sample input and show the corresponding expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `awk`

```
echo "10.04.2017 10:15:05" | awk -F"[. ]" '{print $3"-"$2"."$1,$4}
2017-04.10 10:15:05
```

Setting space and dot as field separator and print it out.
If its middle of something, you may need to find and tweak more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable `string` in awk which reads '10.04.2017 10:14:05' you can split it with field separators and rebuild it:

```
split(string,a,'[. ]')
string_new = a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1]" "a[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date in the 3rd field.

Maybe all you need it to replace `.` to `-` in the 3rd field. Something like this:

```
awk -F "|" '{gsub("\.","-",$3)}1'
```

Please provide some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The following command changes the third field (`$3`) as per your requirement.

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{
    split($3, o, "[. ]" );
    $3 = o[3] "-" o[2] "-" o[1] " " o[4];
    print
}'
```

For the input `dfdsfsdg| kljgslfdjgl|10.04.2017 10:15:05` the output is `dfdsfsdg| kljgslfdjgl|2017-04-10 10:15:05`.